# Axiom of choice in HoTT without sethood requirement

Tags: axiom-of-choice, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

3.8.3 of the HoTT book gives the following as a variant of the axiom of choice:

> $\Pi$ (X : U) (Y : X $\rightarrow$ U), (isSet X) $\rightarrow$ ($\Pi$ (x : X), isSet (Y x)) $\rightarrow$ ($\Pi$ (x : X), $\Vert$ Y x $\Vert$) $\rightarrow$ ($\Vert$ $\Pi$ (x : X), Y x $\Vert$)

but it also comments on some possible modifications of the axiom:

> The restriction in the axiom of choice to types that are sets can be
>   relaxed to a certain extent. For instance, we may allow A and P in
>   (3.8.1), or Y in (3.8.3), to be arbitrary type families; this results in a seemingly stronger statement that is equally consistent.

The phrase 'seemingly stronger' is confusing. Does it mean that the resulting statement *is* stronger? Or does it mean that the difference is only superficial, such that we can actually show

> $\Pi$ (X : U) (Y : X $\rightarrow$ U), (isSet X) $\rightarrow$ ($\Pi$ (x : X), $\Vert$ Y x $\Vert$) $\rightarrow$ ($\Vert$ $\Pi$ (x : X), Y x $\Vert$)

to be equivalent to 3.8.3? Or is the equivalence of two statements an open question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the intent of the book's phrasing was not to imply anything about whether it is actually strictly stronger.  I certainly haven't ever seen a proof that 3.8.3 implies the stronger statement where $Y$ isn't a set; but I don't think I've ever seen a proof that it doesn't either.  Which means that I guess it is an open problem.  I suspect that one of the models in [1508.02410](http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02410) could be found that would satisfy 3.8.3 but not the stronger version, but I haven't checked.